# Firebase Displaying Different Comments From The Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app in Swift similar to those of restaurant rating apps, where users post comments on different restaurants. For now, I can save successfully a user's comment to database with the below code. My app does not require a sign-up or a login screen, users can directly comment as they wish, thus I set the currentUserID as anonymous.

```
@IBAction func OnSubmitTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (textField.text != ""){

       let ref = Database.database().reference()
       let commentsReference = ref.child("comments")
       let newCommentID = commentsReference.childByAutoId().key
       let newCommentReference = commentsReference.child(newCommentID)
       // guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
       //     return
       // }
        var currentUserID = "anonymous"
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
               currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }
       // let currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        newCommentReference.setValue(["uid": currentUserID, "commentText": textField.text!]) { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
}
```

Now, the thing is that when displaying these comments to other users, how can I separate the comments on restaurants in such a way that all restaurants don't end up having the exact same comments section? In the dashboard I could create sub-records for my comments record for every restaurant, however, there are more than 1000 restaurants in the app, it would take an enormous amount of time. Think of restaurant names as cells in a tableview, users cannot add restaurants, they can only add comments.
I'd be very glad if someone can help me out. I know the post is a bit long but I just wanted to make sure that everything is clear. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how you might structure you Firebase database in a sane way such that you can retrieve comments specific to each restaurant. You're also worried about having to fill out the database with all of the names of the restaurants so that the comments will have a place to live. Does that sound about right?

Also what would stop you from storing something like a restaurant name/id with the comment (assuming the comments are made on the restaurant)?

Comment: @ScottChow yes that is right. For storing restaurant names with comments, like I said in my question there are more than a 1000 restaurants so it would take some time to enter all of them in the database. But if its the only way than I'm OK about it, just still not 100% sure how to implement the coding and edit the firebase database. Should I create 1000 different restaurant sub-records under my real comments record and then do 1000 if-else statements to correctly link them to my sub-records? I'd appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so first things first; if you're worried that you won't be able to store data at a location in Firebase because the restaurant node isn't there, don't worry.

When you write to a location (say `comments/restaurantNameOrIDHere/comment1/`), if any node along the way isn't defined (say `comments` or `restaurantNameOrIDHere`), Firebase will create that node for you.

With that out of the way, on to the database structure. There are two ways that immediately jump out at me.

1. Store the restaurant name/id on the comment and store all comments under a `comments/` node.

   - Pros: This keeps your database flatter and more normalized, given that the comment has enough information to allow you to know which restaurant it belongs to.
   - Cons: This would require you to add a field to your comments object. It also means that querying for comments for a specific restaurant is more expensive. It either has to fetch all comments and then filter out the ones that don't belong to the restaurant in question OR it has to filter on the Firebase query, which is more expensive on the Firebase side of things.
2. Store the comment under a restaurant name/id node such as `comments/reallyCoolRestaurant/`.

   - Pros: This allows you to start storing your comments as-is under a restaurant name/id, which means less development time now. It also makes asking for all comments for a given restaurant incredibly cheap and easy.
   - Cons: Accessing all comments becomes slightly more of a hassle, given that they're distributed in many different restaurant nodes.

I'd personally leaning towards a combination of the two for the following reasons:

- Storing the comments in buckets based on what restaurant they belong to makes asking for a restaurant's comments easy and efficient.
- Storing the restaurant a comment belongs to could potentially be useful in future cases where you might want to pull out and analyze comments for restaurants.

If you wanted to keep simple and just pick one, I'd go for the second option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I think I can use the second option. Just to make sure that I got the right idea, I don't need to create 1000(the number of restaurants) nodes specific to each restaurant under my father comment node in the firebase database manually. In XCode, I can check in a function which restaurant (tableview cell) the user has clicked on with 1000 if-else statements so that I can know which restaurant the user has chosen and then add a node to the firebase database using the statement comments/chosenRestaurantName/  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out now!!!  Thank you a thousand times for your help!!!

Comment: I would suggest that you use the index of the cell that was clicked on to determine the restaurant that was clicked on.